# nullable column with Postgres API

Tags: c, postgresql, api

With libfq and the C API, is there a way to get the nullable metadata of a column from a query?

I'm just talking about the property of a column, not the NULL value from a resultset.

For instance, with MySQL:

> mysql_fetch_field_direct()

does the job.

I tried with PQfmod, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about the table definition is not part of the result set data.

You can find out if the value is `NULL`, but not if the column is nullable or not.

A column in a result set need not be related to a certain column in a table!

To get information about a column's definition, query `information_schema.columns`. The `is_nullable` column will contain the information.